# Which companion for a stealth character?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm playing a stealth (sniper) character and at the moment have Dogmeat as my companion, but I have to tell him to stay behind a lot because he gets spotted or gets in the way a lot.

**Is any of the other companions more compatible with a stealth character?**

In FO:NV I used Boone when travelling outside, since he would usually be able to shoot from our position instead of moving forward and attracting even more enemies.

Comment: The archetype sounds more like you'd not want a companion, and take the Lone Wanderer perk instead.

Comment: @David Yell, lone wanderer is a perk that supports using Dog(meat), which appears to be against OPs request.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Deacon#Other_interactions) Deacon is the companion with the highest natural sneak skill.

If you equip him with a sniper rifle, he will have the same range as you.

Comment: His perk is also stealth related, which can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

One problem with companions is that they can be seen prematurely by the enemies. With [console](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Fallout_4_console_commands), `Send 01234567.CallFunction "Actor.StartSneaking"` might be a useful [command](https://www.creationkit.com/fallout4/index.php?title=Actor_Script) (where `01234567` is companion ID). (But keep a save before trying it out.)

Or else, simply having a hotkey to tell companion where to go - might be very useful, as it makes it easier for us to manage companion visibility.

Example of an AutoHotkey script to hotkey companion control:

```
Control::
  Send {~ Down}
  Sleep 123
  Send {~ Up}
  Sleep 123
  Send 01234567.setcommandstate 1
  Sleep 123
  Send {Enter Down}
  Sleep 123
  Send {Enter Up}
  Sleep 123
  Send {~ Down}
  Sleep 123
  Send {~ Up}
  Sleep 123
  Send {e Down}
  Sleep 123
  Send {e Up}
  Sleep 123
  Send {Tab Down}
  Sleep 123
  Send {Tab Up}
  Sleep 123
  Send {Tab Down}
  Sleep 123
  Send {Tab Up}
  Return
```

[Ada](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Ada) has a Stealth Field torso upgrade, which boosts the Sole Survivor stealth capabilities. Her Recon Sensors can also be useful.
While flying and under `StartSneaking` she looks normal, but moves slower than usual (running `SetPlayerTeammate` would change that).
Her arm can be made into a Stealth Blade.